# NextJS 13: does not work onClick but the component uses 'use client;'

Tags: reactjs, select, next.js, onclick, next.js13

I try to implement the select component. However, I noticed that my onClick function did not work. I don't know why, because I used 'use client;' for my component.

```
"use client";
import React from "react";
import styles from "./select.module.scss";

...

export const ChartSelect: React.FC<{
  chartType: "monthly" | "yearly" | "half-yearly";
  setChartType: React.Dispatch<
    React.SetStateAction<"monthly" | "yearly" | "half-yearly">
  >;
}> = (props) => {
  ...

  const handleOnClick = (value: "monthly" | "yearly" | "half-yearly") => {
    console.log("handleOnClick");
    props.setChartType(value);
  };

  return (
    <div className={styles.wrapper}>
      <div className={styles.select}>{findLabelByValue(props.chartType)}</div>
      <div className={styles.dropdown}>
        {options.map((option) => (
          <div
            className={styles.option}
            onClick={() => {
              console.log("PURE ONCLICK");
              handleOnClick(option.value);
            }}
          >
            {option.label}
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: When you say it doesn't work, do you mean it never fires? As in, you do not see `"PURE ONCLICK"` in your browser console?

Comment: It never fires. I know the console displays in the next js console, not in the browser.

Comment: `onClick` is client-side interactivity, so any logs will show in the browser console, not the server.

Comment: Any solution to this?
I added "use client", yet I see my logs only on the CLI. Then my onClick function does not fire at all.

Answer (score 0):

Downgrade to 13.4.16. It worked for me.

Looks like this is an error for the lastest version:

https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/54269

Hot reload isn't working for me with the lastest

Answer (score -1):

Please update your node version. It fixed my problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).